# play system sound for UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I found this project on GitHub: [iOS Sounds and Ringtones](https://github.com/CQH/iOS-Sounds-and-Ringtones)

Is there a way to play one of those sounds for `localNotification.soundName`?

So I got the string for `"/Library/RingtonesApex.m4r"`

But it still plays the default notification sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UILocalNotification` accepts only a sound file name, not a file path. And the docs for `soundName` explain that this file must be *"...in the app’s main bundle..."*. Getting the path to a system sound file is not useful with `UILocalNotification` because that file is not in your app's main bundle, and because you can't tell `UILocalNotification` to look somewhere else.

Comment: So it is impossible?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If you want to use a sound with a local notification, that sound needs to be in your app bundle.

Comment: Is there a way to import those system sounds so I can add it to the bundle?

Comment: You could write an app to copy them to the app's documents directory. Then you could use Xcode to download the app's data to your Mac. Get the sounds out of the downloaded data and add them to your real app. But Apple might reject your app for including copyrighted material (Apple's copyrighted material) or for using their system sounds in ways they don't like.

Answer (score 1):

Surely possible , you need just to move the custom sound you need to this path :
Library/Sounds ,,,by default Sounds folder is not under library ,so you need to create it , then copy any custom sound file (either after downloading to documents then copy or copying system sound ) to this directory as i said  Library/Sounds . According to Apple , Sound files should be in bundle (in case get shipped with app) or in ONLY this directory Library/Sounds . You can assign only sound file name with any extension to the sound name property in local notification before iOS 10 and after iOS 10 you can assign ti to content sound name constructor . I tried it several times before and both worked for local and remote notification by either playing sound from remote server or system sound . If you need any help putting this to work in any swift versions or objective-c you're welcome .

Comment: Yes, and at the place of soundName in the local or push notification payload just put the name of the sound file which you just copied to the Library/Sounds path.

Comment: but is it possible for system sounds like ringtones to copy to the Library/Sounds path?

Comment: Hi @DheerajGupta , this really interesting question and the answer is yes it’s totally doable. I was asked for this before and to what I remember i set from server payload system sound as notification.caf , then showed list of ringtones to user(system sounds) , once user choose one i copy it under library/sounds with the name notification.caf to override the default notification sound . If you’re interested can submit my code later . Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, please @IsPha, it would be a great help. I am struggling since yesterday, how to copy system ringtone to Library/Sounds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171156/discussion-between-ispha-and-dheeraj-gupta).

Comment: hope if you got it from chat message :D

Comment: Yes @IsPha, I got the code from chat message but i could not try it at my end. But thanks, it seems that it will work.

Comment: it worked. Thanks a lot, I was thinking that it won't be possible due to apple's limitations but you proof me wrong. Really, thanks..

Comment: You’re more than welcome actually and really glad you worked out your issue.

Comment: would you provide an example please

Answer (score 0):

Set for your UILocalNotification soundName property

```
UILocalNotification *localNoti = [UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNoti.soundName = @"your sound with file format (exmpl.m4r)";
```

And make sure that your sound no longer than 30 sec. It's a limit of sound length
Hope this help

Comment: This is what I did. Like you can see in my question.

Comment: check path to your audio file, they need be in bundle of your app

Comment: the audio file is located on every iOS Device. So I didn't import anything

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the repo you linked to in the original post.

Unfortunately, you cannot refer to the path of the sound in a localNotification. You have to have the file in the app bundle (i.e. a .MP3 file attached to your app) to use it as a custom sound.